# Scroll inside a table (Fixed Header) Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed-header-tables

I am doing a color-map table, but I have a lot of columns and rows (so many cells...)  I need to do an scroll inside the table similar to Excel tables. Do you have any idea for beginning my code?

Comment: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try javascript library **Datatables**

https://datatables.net/manual/installation

This library contains virtual rendering plug-in named ***scroller***.

This is how it should look like:

[image: this is how it should look like]

Comment: @victor try it and write feedback if u have any problems with implementing :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your table in a div and set the height on the div.
Then you set `overflow: auto` on the containing div to achieve this result.

http://jsfiddle.net/uh6705mx/2/

Comment: Thank u for your help, but I need a fixed header, like an Excel sheet